# Is it possible to switch to the next element from the active element in selenium?

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, webdriver

For example, the active element is the input element. But I need to be able to switch to the span element in order to click the checkbox. I can't use xpath or css selectors because this is part of a dynamic table where the element path changes every time. I have tried using Actions and moving to the element before clicking it but it doesn't work. The only other way I can think of is to create a hashmap and store the key associated with the checkbox with the checkbox value (on/off) but this seems to be a lot for something quite trivial.

```
<div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input class="ace" data-element-name="compulsory" type="checkbox">
          <span class="lbl"></span>
        </label>
 </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "switch"? what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I guess `dynamic xpath` should work here properly.  xpath = `//input[@data-element-name='compulsory'][@type='checkbox']`

Comment: Using Span tag move ahead to click on check-box xpath = `//span[@class='lbl']/preceding-sibling::input[@data-element-name='compulsory'][@type='checkbox']`

Comment: All I want to do is click on the checkbox located at the span tag but when I tab to the checkbox the input tag is now in focus and not the span tag so the click() and sendKeys(Keys.SPACE) don't work. The checkbox is located in a row of a dynamic table.

Comment: I used a loop instead working now.

Comment: Not all elements have onFocus attribute; so you just can't hit TAB to reach that element

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was wrong with @JainishKapadia 's second xpath suggestion? Although I'd do it a bit different `//input[@class='ace'][@type='checkbox']/following-sibling::*[@class='lbl']`

Comment: If there is data in the row, you can make a method that will take in some text, and find the correct checkbox for you, if there is really nothing unique in the elements themselves to identify which checkbox you want. That would make your tests more robust, but I'd need a bit more html for the table to help with that.

Comment: I got a could not find element exception when I used the xpath above. But I have it working now by using the css selector and incrementing the value of the table e.g. td:nth-child(i) .